# Large Neo4j graph not showing up

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I created a large neo4j graph connecting users to the videos they watch like user -> video in a social graph or network type of graph. There are about 9000 user nodes and 20000 video nodes.

If I try:

```
MATCH (u)-[:VIEW]->(v)
RETURN u,v
```

The graph says "Displaying 300000 nodes, 0 relationships." No graph nor relationships nor nodes are showing up.

If I try:

```
MATCH (u)-[:VIEW]->(v)
RETURN u,v
LIMIT 1000
```

The graph says "Displaying 1000 nodes, 1000 relationships (completed with 1000 additional relationships)." All graph and relationships and nodes show up.

If I try:

```
MATCH (u)-[:VIEW]->(v)
RETURN u,v
LIMIT 10000
```

No graph nor relationships nor nodes show up.

Is the first graph too large to show? How can I get it to show up?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which Neo4j version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you doing this in the web console?  I suspect when you do the `LIMIT 10000` that the result is just too big to be handled in the web browser. I'm actually a bit surprised that 1000 showed up (again, if you're in the web console).

What are you trying to get?  If you want to get a table you can do this (I'm making up properties here):

```
MATCH (u)-[:VIEW]->(v)
RETURN u.username,v.title
```

If you want something else, then I'd need more information ;)

Comment: Yes I am doing this in the web console. How else can I do this? Command line maybe?  That is the code I am using and I do get the whole table. It is simply the graph that does not appear.

Comment: D3's graph visualization is not made for that large graphs so there is a configured limit of what the Neo4j browser will display, but there should be a warning.

Comment: Yes, you can use the web console, `neo4j-shell`, or the REST endpoints.  I guess what I'm asking is, what are you trying to find out?  Or any you trying to get a sense of your data?  If you want a larger picture of your data you might want something like Gephi.  Cypher and particularly the web console are good for aggregating and summarizing